# Does voice doubling an instrument's melody while improvising have a name?

Tags: voice, jazz, instruments, melody

According to wikipedia, **scat singing** is:

> In vocal jazz, scat singing is vocal improvisation with wordless
> vocables, nonsense syllables or without words at all.[2][3] In scat
> singing, the singer improvises melodies and rhythms using the voice as
> an instrument rather than a speaking medium.

But does it have a name when you **sing doubling the melody of the instrument you are playing while improvising**? This is very common in jazz music, related to scat (that's why I mentioned it).

For example ...

This can only be possible in instruments like guitar, piano and bass for obvious reasons.

Comment: Do you mean the singer is impersonating the sound of an instrument? So singing to sound as much like a muted trumpet as possible, say?

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS [Here's an example of what I mean](https://youtu.be/GprrW0TtAJ8?t=1827). It's common in instruments like guitar, piano and bass, not for "mouth" instruments for obvious reasosns.

Comment: Side comment, let alone the naming of it: It is extremely useful for improvising to sing along your playing! If a solo is singable, it is most likely a good solo with good lines and phrasing!

Too bad it doesn't have a name! Something useful should definately have a name! :-)

Comment: @AsgeirNesøen Yeah, and I think is good for the ear too. If you can sing it it's because you have the music in your mind and not in your fingers. ☺️

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case where an instrumentalist doubles their own improvisation with voice, there is not a specific term. [Slam Stewart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slam_Stewart) made his name [doubling his bass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmGHZrGZFgA&t=1m14s) in this way, having gotten the idea from [Ray Perry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Perry), who did the same in his violin solos (recording not readily available). In general, it's considered something of a novelty.

Some musicians famously vocalize while they play, but not with the intentionality of a Slam Stewart. Standout examples are [Glenn Gould](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glenn_Gould#Eccentricities) and [Keith Jarrett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Jarrett#Idiosyncrasies). In this video, Glenn Gould is actually [singing along](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qB76jxBq_gQ) (about 5 sec. in), though not with the intention of featuring his voice. And here is a compilation of [Keith Jarrett vocalizations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWEe1JKY7mI).

[An article](https://www.kqed.org/news/10946244/keith-jarrett-and-his-involuntary-vocalizations) published by radio station KQED characterizes Jarrett's (and Gould's) vocalizations as "involuntary."

**Vocalese** is the term for adding lyrics to and singing an instrumental melody. The term is sometimes also applied to any vocal realization on an instrumental part.

Wikipedia has a good [entry on the term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocalese) and some history of the practice.

To pick just one particularly well-known example, [Eddie Jefferson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Jefferson) turned [James Moody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Moody_(saxophonist))'s improvisation on "[I'm in the Mood for Love](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwbgQDPiSuU)" (link to Frances Langford's premier of the song) into a vocalese version.

Here is a YouTube link to [James Moody's version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9tAkvpOaMU). (Introduction by Dizzy Gillespie; James Moody begins at 1:45)
And here is "[Moody's Mood for Love](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAe1C6y7IEU)" by Eddie Jefferson.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no; the style of scat singing in unison along with an instrumental solo, or doubling it at an octave (like George Benson) does not have a specific, concise  name (as far as I can tell).