# What do you call it when someone sings a melody and simultaneously plays the exact same melody?

Tags: voice, terminology, melody

What do you call it when someone sings a melody while another instrument plays the exact same melody in unison?

For example:

1. "Crosstown Traffic" – The Jimi Hendrix Experience, intro: a guitar riff plays and is doubled by a voice singing the riff using the syllable "doo" over and over again.
2. "Smells Like Teen Spirit" – Nirvana, 2min40secs: the guitar plays a certain bend and Kurt Cobain sings the word "Hey" in unison with the guitar.

The examples I provided are from what would broadly be called popular music but I'd also be interested in hearing about the technique from a classical perspective.

Comment: I feel like there's a certain jazz guitar (and bass) convention in which one would play and scat-sing their improvisation simultaneously in unison. For a classical perspective, I just came from a rehearsal of Handel's *Messiah*, where the violins spend much of the time "doubling" choir parts.

Comment: Thanks @AndyBonner. Regarding the jazz convention you mention - could you point me towards a famous example of that, maybe with a single person who is a lead guitarist playing and vocal scatting in unison?

Comment: As in my answer - George Benson does this a LOT.

Comment: That note in "Smells Like Teen Spirit" is an *ensemble* : "a group producing a single effect" because the drummer is in on it too.

Comment: @Tim Pretty sure Oteil Burbridge does this a lot as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's called **doubling**. The term is correctly used in the OP: in the intro to "Crosstown Traffic", Jimi doubles the vocal melody on guitar (or the guitar melody on voice).

For example:

> 2. When an accompanying instrument plays the same notes that a singer is singing. (Source: [OnMusic Dictionary](https://dictionary.onmusic.org/terms/1207-doubling))

Wikipedia also discusses the term in its article on voicing in music:

> Octave doubling of a voice or pitch is a number of other voices duplicating the same part at the same pitch or at different octaves. (Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voicing_(music)#Doubling))

The term is used across styles of music.

One example from classical music — both of the technique itself and the use of the term — comes from Liszt's song "Comment, disaient-ils" for voice and piano (S.276). In measures 12 – 18, the vocal melody is doubled by the top voice of the piano part.

Here is a description from a dissertation discussing some of Liszt's songs:<sup>1</sup>

> In the original version, the descending melody in the voice is doubled in the piano over a waltz-like left-hand accompaniment. (Source: "[Franz Liszt's Songs on Poems by Victor Hugo](https://diginole.lib.fsu.edu/islandora/object/fsu:180473/datastream/PDF)", by Shin-Young Park, PhD diss., Florida State University, 2007, p. 20)

[image: "Comment disaient-ils", mm. 9 – 18]
(Image source: [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Comment_disaient-ils%2C_S.276_(Liszt%2C_Franz)))

Doubling can also refer to 1) a note that appears more than once within a chord, or 2) a musician who plays more than one instrument (James Moody played tenor sax and doubled on flute).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>A couple of other examples of the term's use: 1) "The voice is doubled in the piano for the first time in the song in mm. 21-22, expressing the unity of our couple." ("[Glances: an Analysis of the Song Cycle by Tom Cipullo](https://digitalcommons.memphis.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1448&context=etd)", Renee Mae Clair, PhD diss., University of Memphis, 2011, p. 50); 2) "Then, for the last few lines of text, though the chords in the piano remain dissonant, the voice is doubled in the piano chords." ("[Song Cycles for Soprano by Richard Pearson Thomas](https://digscholarship.unco.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1071&context=dissertations)", Laura Faith Bateman, PhD diss., University of Northern Colorado, 2011, p. 74)</sub>

Comment: It could be called doubling, and certainly now after becoming an internet truth as per this answer, someone _will_ call it doubling, but do you have references of e.g. the player-singer calling it doubling themselves? Prior to 11/2022. ;) Myself, I would describe it as unison something, but I don't think I've actually heard that in the way the OP means, either. On Reddit they couldn't come up with a clear term back in 2014 https://www.reddit.com/r/Jazz/comments/2fgjdc/what_is_called_when_a_musician_will_sing_unison/   "Vocalizing", "scat" and "vocalizing in unison" were suggested.

Comment: Doubling could be used when someone uses two different instruments , on a recording, for example, and gets paid twice. For playing a different part, though. (As your last sentence hints). I don't think it's exactly the right word, as playing *in unison* is a proper, accepted term for what's happening. Just as 'the whole horn section played in unison' - take Sir Duke as an example. That one 'instrument is a voice is immaterial, I believe.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica I wonder if you're thinking of "vocalese": [Does voice doubling an instrument's melody while improvising have a name?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/102218/70803).

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica humming along with your solo seems different from what the question is asking, which I think is more generally about a singer "doubling" an instrument (or vice versa).

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica I've added some references. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: This is really a different meaning and point of view than what I was thinking. In doubling, the doubler follows something that's pre-defined or somehow comes from outside. But in improvised solos, when the soloist does both the singing and the playing, it's one single thing, like a technique. The OP's question leaves both perspectives somewhat open, with the  single-word "Hey" in Smells like teen spirit. That's quite different from what e.g. George Benson does. But I don't think Jimi thought of his singing as doubling himself. I left it up to the OP to decide which meaning he really meant.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica: In classical music, *doubling* is a very well-established term, and it applies here but is also a lot more general, so it needs to include clarification — “Cobain was doubling” in isolation is meaningless, but “Cobain doubles the guitar riff in the vocals” is completely clear and accurate.  “Doubling” doesn’t necessarily mean following an external source, it just means two voices/instruments playing the same line (or at octaves apart).  It’s standard and commonly-used among classical musicians; I’ve no idea if it’s also used much or at all among jazz players.

Comment: @PLL "Let's double" is meaningless, and "I'll double something over these chord changes" is equally nonsensical. Are you going to randomly select another instruments voice and double that? "Let's double the melody" does make sense, but you'll have to have a melody to start with. In contrast "I did some vocalizing in my solo" is sensible. It's up to the OP to specify which perspective he was after, and for what kind of use he wants a word.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Slam Stewart famously doubled his (improvised) bass solos on voice — or vice versa. The term is in common usage with that meaning, always used in reference to the thing being doubled: "The X was doubled (by the Y)." While "vocalizing" refers to the voice, it's even less specific and must be used with reference to the thing being ... doubled. "George Benson vocalized" means anything involving his voice. "George Benson vocalized along with his guitar" would mean he made vocal sounds while playing the guitar. "George Benson doubled his guitar on vocals" has clear meaning.

Comment: That's really just your opinions about how people should speak. The choice of word depends on... how you put your words. It may well be that from now on, with the answer having a high internet truth score, people will start to use words more like you'd recommend. I found a word for it that people have actually used, in a meaning that's suitable for _some_ ways of talking about it. "I like to vocalize in my solos", short and understandable for some purposes. Are you suggesting that the OP _should not want_ to use language like that, because that way of speaking is not ... something enough? :)

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Actually, yes. I'm saying that OP should not use "vocalize" for the purpose of describing vocal accompaniment to an instrumental (or vice versa). In music circles, that term is not used with that meaning. "Doubling", while not specific to vocals, has a clear, well established meaning that applies to the situation being asked about and is in common, longstanding use among musicians.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Neither of the asker’s examples are improvised solos. It’s the exact same thing as in orchestration when a composer or orchestrator says "I doubled the flute line on first violins". It’s just in this case, Jimi doubled the guitar line on voice and Kurt doubled the guitar "sting" on voice. I’ve definitely heard "doubling" used in this context - Aaron did not invent this.

Answer (score 7):

Unison is another term - singing (or playing) the same melody as another. Doubling is more often used to describe the *same* instrument (or voice) playing/singing the same line. George Benson is a great example of someone who plays and sings in unison.

Scat *could* come into the equation, with non-sensical 'words', although usually, that's not what is asked about here, and won't necessarily follow the melody line of another instrument, although the non-sensical part is applicable.

Answer (score 4):

In this Reddit discussion from 2014, "vocalizing" (or "vocalising") was mentioned in three different posts as an actually used term:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Jazz/comments/2fgjdc/what_is_called_when_a_musician_will_sing_unison/

Vocalizing has other meanings as well, and one person in that discussion suggests "vocalising in unison", which would feel like a pretty clear name for the technique.

One quote from the discussion

> I'm quite sure it's called vocalising, both when it's the same line as
> the solo (eg. Slam Stewart, Esperanza Spalding), and when it's not
> related to the solo (eg. Keith Jarrett). A better term for the first
> instance is probably vocalising in unison, or harmonising in unison.
> Scat singing is another thing that only vocalists do (putting
> syllables to a solo played by a vocalist rather than just humming a
> melody.

"Doubling" was not mentioned by anyone in that discussion, if that proves something.

Comment: @Rucksack I think this is closest to what you're thinking and suggests that (like so many things in jazz) it's a thing people do but doesn't necessarily have an established name.

Comment: This is incorrect. "Vocalizing" is a general term for any vocal sound produced. Portions of the reddit thread acknowledge this: "I'm quite sure it's called vocalising, both when it's the same line as the solo (eg. Slam Stewart, Esperanza Spalding), and when it's not related to the solo (eg. Keith Jarrett)." The posters on that thread may be confusing the term "vocalize" (vo - cal - eyes) with "vocalise" (vo - cal - ees). In classical music, vocalise refers to textless vocal melody, and in jazz it refers to putting lyrics to an instrumental improvisation.

Comment: @Aaron The term has other uses and is ambiguous without context. So what. OP asks, what is it called, which means, "what do people call it." I presented a reference of people actually calling it vocalizing. People call it vocalizing, here's proof. And I have a hard time believing that George Benson would say to someone, "the audience liked it when I doubled." But "the audience liked it when I vocalized", that feels plausible. "I'll vocalize a bit for you", yes. But "I'll double a bit for you", no.

Comment: In the Reddit as with here, it's along the lines of "I think people would call it ...". Vocalizing is a broad, generic term. George Benson very well might say "the audience liked my vocalization", but it would be entirely unclear whether he meant solo singing, accompanying his guitar with voice, or both. It would also be unclear whether he meant singing or grunting, since both are vocalizations. On the other hand, if he said "I like to double my guitar with my vocals (or vice versa)", there would be no ambiguity.

Comment: @Aaron It's not incorrect, I'm familiar with the term "vocalize" used this way.  I've heard advice to "vocalize while improvising" to avoid haphazardly playing notes based on fingering patterns.

Comment: @Edward I don't doubt you've heard that advice, but I bet it was clear from context that "singing" was meant. Keith Jarrett vocalizes while he improvises, but it's definitely not singing — it's a high-pitched whine, which he is not conscious of making.

Comment: I’m sure this answer is **also** correct. One reason why I’m comfortable that other answers have higher scores is that I’ve personally never heard "vocalizing" used this way, but I’ve absolutely heard "doubling" and "in unison" used in this context.

Comment: @Aaron - I'm pretty sure George Benson could also say 'I'm singing in unison with my guitar playing.'

Comment: @Tim Absolutely, that would be a correct statement — unless he was doubling at the octave.

Comment: @Aaron - which he rarely does.